# Get the attributes duplicated in a node XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xls

I try to get duplicate address for a object but i don't understand why my foreach doesn't work. I think it's because of the function generate-id().

I expect the following result :

`<ul>
        <li>1.1.1.1</li>
        <li>host1</li>
        <li>host2</li>
        <li>host5</li>
        <li>host7</li>
    </ul>`

`<ul>
        <li>2.2.2.2</li>
        <li>host8</li>
        <li>host9</li>
    </ul>`

Your help would be appreciated

This is my xls :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Template</TITLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:key name="same-ip" match="db/OBJECT/PROPERTY[@NAME='address']" use="@VALUE" />
  <xsl:template match="db/OBJECT">

    <xsl:for-each select="//db/OBJECT/PROPERTY[@NAME='address']/@VALUE[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('same-ip',@VALUE)[1])]"> 
      <ul>
      <li><xsl:value-of select='//db/OBJECT/PROPERTY[@NAME="address"]/@VALUE'/> </li>
      <li><xsl:value-of select='//db/OBJECT/PROPERTY[@NAME="host"]/@VALUE'/> </li>
      </ul>
   </xsl:for-each> 

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="trans-simple.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<db>
<OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host1" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="1.1.1.1" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host2" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="1.1.1.1" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host3" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="3.3.3.3" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host4" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="4.4.4.4" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host5" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="1.1.1.1" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host7" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="1.1.1.1" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host8" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="2.2.2.2" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  <OBJECT>
    <PROPERTY NAME="__type"
    VALUE=".com.enterprise.dns.host_address" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="rrset_order_position" VALUE="0" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="host"
    VALUE="host9" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="is_ipv4" VALUE="true" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="2.2.2.2" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="v6_prefix" VALUE="" />
    <PROPERTY NAME="configure_for_dhcp" VALUE="false" />
  </OBJECT>
  </db>
```

Comment: Can you show us which result you want? Or at least explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just add the expected result. I need to fix the xsl  now.

Comment: Do you want to group objects based on the PROPERTY NAME="address" ?

Comment: Yes, i want to to group object by PROPERTY NAME="address".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you are trying to use is called Muenchian grouping. You are trying to group your 'host' properties, by the 'address' property.

Firstly, you have defined the key correctly, although in this case it could be simplified to the following if your XML didn't contain **PROPERTY** elements under differently named elements

```
<xsl:key name="same-ip" match="PROPERTY[@NAME='address']" use="@VALUE"/>
```

The next stage in Muenchian grouping is to loop through the first element in each group (In your case, the first 'host' propertry for each 'address' property). This will get you your distinct groups.

This is how it should be written:

```
<xsl:for-each 
  select="db/OBJECT/PROPERTY
    [@NAME='address']
    [generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('same-ip',@VALUE)[1])]">
```

Actually, it is better practise to use **xsl:apply-templates** in this case, rather than a **xsl:for-each**

Then, you just need to loop through all the matching elements in the same group, which can be done be using the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('same-ip', @VALUE)">
```

Here is the final XSLT. Note I am using **xsl:apply-templates** here rather than a **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="same-ip" match="PROPERTY[@NAME='address']" use="@VALUE"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <HTML>
         <HEAD>
            <TITLE>Template</TITLE>
         </HEAD>
         <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
              select="db/OBJECT/PROPERTY
                [@NAME='address']
                [generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('same-ip',@VALUE)[1])]" mode="group"/>
         </BODY>
      </HTML>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="PROPERTY[count(key('same-ip', @VALUE)) &gt; 1]" mode="group">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@VALUE"/>
         </li>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('same-ip', @VALUE)"/>
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="PROPERTY">
      <li>
         <xsl:value-of select="../PROPERTY[@NAME='host']/@VALUE"/>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your given XML, the following is output

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Template</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
      <ul>
         <li>1.1.1.1</li>
         <li>host1</li>
         <li>host2</li>
         <li>host5</li>
         <li>host7</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>2.2.2.2</li>
         <li>host8</li>
         <li>host9</li>
      </ul>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Do note the following line, which matches the first element in each group

```
<xsl:template match="PROPERTY[count(key('same-ip', @VALUE)) &gt; 1]" mode="group">
```

I had assumed from your given result, you wanted to ignore groups with one element (i.e. 'Address' Properties, with only one 'host' property). If this is not the case, simply change it to the following to output everything:

```
<xsl:template match="PROPERTY" mode="group">
```

Also note the use of the **mode** attribute to avoid the first template calling itself recursively which would lead to a stack overflow.